# How to implement push notification for multiple Android apps?

Tags: android, service, push, notifications

Our products still target OS 1.5+, so C2DM in Froyo is not an option.

I think wrap a persistent TCP connection in a service would be feasible. But I'm still wondering how to use one service to receive notifications for multiple applications. I don't want to create service and connection for each of my apps.

Should I try to register the same service in all my apps, or release the service as a single app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at what Urban Airship has done with their implementation of push notifications for Android pre-2.2. They have a centralized application called AirMail Control Panel which configures push settings for multiple applications that use their push service.

The documentation is [here](http://urbanairship.com/docs/android_client.html).